# Azure Data Factory: Copy Data activity always returning error from REST or HTTP source datasets

Tags: azure, dataset, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use the Azure Data Factory to create a simple example of extracting data from a REST API and save in a Azure SQL Database.

Linked Service (REST)

- Base URL: `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/`
- Authentication:
- Anonymous Test Connection -> Connection Successful

Dataset (REST)

- Linked Service: (the service created above)
- Relative URL: `api/v1/employees`
- Test Connection -> Connection Successful

Pipeline

- Copy Data activity
- Source Dataset: (the dataset created above)
- Request method: GET
- Preview data -> Failed.

Message:

```
Failed to get response from server, please check network connection and retry.
Contact support or send feedback if the issue persists. Activity ID:d466c55d-d3f3-4216-b560-df84c33ff0b6
```

I have tried multiple different endpoints, from different providers, but no luck.

The above endpoint works perfectly on Postman or browser.

Answer (score 0):

Which region is the ADF in ? 
Mine is in EAST US and the setup which you mentioned is the same and it works for me.Are you on self hosted integration runtime(SHIR)?

Are you able to preview the data at the dataset level ? My understanding is error  which you mentioning in the question is at the Copy activity level .